# Calculating a Service Health based on different parameters

Tags: math, statistics, analytics, mean, scoring

For one of our services we are mapping the dependencies of the service components based on how the components of the service interact and provide a response to the user.This mapping of dependencies will be in the form of a graph.

Now ultimately we have to provide a score for the service on how good it is.So for each of the components we collect few performance metrics and see how the data points for that metric are for example the metric can be cpu utilization.

I need some pointers on aggregating the scores for each of these dependencies.

If we should use averages or any other mathematical concepts.

Answer (score 1):

see if you find this usefull:
Usually SCOM does a good job in monitoring services and system health. Based on the health that it calculates taking into account all dependencies it gives a system overall health status.
Usually the dependencies of a service should have a health threshold somewhere around 60%ish .. or at least this is how SCOM does it.

You also have to define priorities for the dependencies, like which one is more important.

Hopes this helps

Comment: Yes defining the priorities is what the most toughest part is for services whose state keeps on changing and we don't for sure which metrics are affecting.I am looking for some in depth concepts to aggregate components performance scores in an intuitive way.